# Drupal, Translating menu PATHS

Tags: drupal, internationalization

Is it possible to translate a menu path in Drupal using i18n? In other words, basically creating two different links, namely:
  www.mysite.com/english  -- www.mysite.com/german
In other words, not just altering the paths, but supporting external links for translation.

And if so... how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I don't understand completely - if you enable multiple languages, every link gets a language prefix automatically, like /en, /it etc. You can anyway alter every URL via an URL alias, a seperate one for each language.

Comment: In Drupal, when you create nodes, you can translate those nodes and it will automatically create the prefixes. My question is regarding creating menu items directly that link OFFSITE to for example link1.com and link2.au. One menu item must be on mysite.com that changes the menu items destination based on the language. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, and you can achieve it very simply: just edit a menu item and change the language from "All languages" to the language it shall appear in.

Answer (score 0):

you can't translate menu path but you can translate their alias, when you activate path module you can manually set a different path for every defined language.

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about external urls, based on the language you are viewing in your drupal site - you'd just create a different language specific menu item points to the external site.  So when you're viewing your site in spanish, you'd only see the external spanish link, and the english, german, etc counterparts would be hidden